# iOS 10 Content and Service extension

Tags: notifications, apns, ios

What is the difference between Content and Service extension?
I just started learning iOS 10 this week and I wrote a simple app displaying rich push notifications.
I had to use Service and Content extensions to process rich notifications before display.
I was wondering what's the subtle difference between the two and how do I use them?
I used Content extension to change the label of push at run time and used Service extension to download an image to be displayed on the push message.
Still thought of asking this question so that my understanding of using them is correct.